# How to create typescript project to use Redux in VS 2017 using RequireJS loader

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-thunk

Please could any one explain the steps to create a `Redux` with typescript project in `Visual studio 2017`.
I need to use `RequireJs` as a loader.

And explanation about how redux plays its role in maintaining a state would be very helpful.

Comment: Add more details about what you want exactly. With more precise question you have more change to have great response !

Comment: Thanks Gearnode , I need step by step process to create a Typescript project to use Redux (a simple project) in VS 2017 (not in VS code) and use RequireJS as a loader .